# Question regarding determinants of a sequence of anti-symmetric matrices.

Tags: determinant, skew-symmetric-matrices

I have a sequence of real anti-symmetric matrices $M(k),k=1,2,\dots$, where $M(k)$ is a $2k\times 2k$ matrix with $(i,j)$ th element defined as
$$
M(k)_{ij} =\frac{i-j}{i+j},\,1\le i\le2k,\, \,1\le j\le2k
$$

Using Mathematica, I calculated $f(k)=\sqrt {\displaystyle\frac{\det(M(k))}{\det(M(k+1))}}$ for first few matrices.

$$
f(1)=350,\, f(2)=58212, \,f(3)=11042460, \,f(4)=2245709180, \,f(5)=476899543848
$$

I was surprised to see whole numbers as answer. Can anyone please help me prove or disprove that $f(k)$ is a whole number for all k.

Comment: It might help if you said why you are looking at these numbers. (And to save labour if you said what the first few $M(k)$ are.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here $[a_{ij}]$ notation means matrix with elements $a_{ij}$.

Let $n = 2k$

$$
\det\left(\left[\frac{i-j}{i+j}\right]\right)
= \det\left(\left[\frac{i-j}{i+j} - 1\right]\right)
= \det\left(\left[\frac{-2j}{i+j}\right]\right)
= 2^n n! \det\left(\left[\frac{1}{i+j}\right]\right).
$$

First equivlence is proved in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1751118/a-is-an-antisymmetric-matrix-of-even-size-b-is-another-matrix-such-that-b-i). (Credits to [@user10001](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/29754/user10001) for pointing out in comments that it is not as trivial as I originally thought, and for finding the reference for the proof).

Matrix $\left[\frac{1}{i+j}\right]$ is closely related to [Hilbert matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix). This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1581447/157345) tells that $\det\left(\left[\frac{1}{i+j}\right]\right)=\det H_n / \binom{2n}{n}$. We'll use formula from the wikipedia for the determinant of Hilbert matrix:
$$
\det H_n = \frac{\left( \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} i! \right)^4}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{2n-1}i!}.
$$

Putting all together we get:
$$
\det M(k) = \frac{2^n n! \left( \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} i! \right)^4 \cdot n! \cdot n!}{\prod\limits_{i=1}^{2n-1}i! \cdot (2n)!}
= \frac{2^n \left( \prod\limits_{i=1}^{n} i! \right)^4}{n! \cdot \prod\limits_{i=1}^{2n}i!}.
$$

Simplifying $M(k)/M(k+1)$ we get:
$$
\frac{\det M(k)}{\det M(k+1)} = \frac{(n+1)(n+2)(2n+1)!(2n+2)!(2n+3)!(2n+4)!}{4((n+1)!(n+2)!)^4} \\= \frac14 \cdot \frac{(2n+1)!}{n!(n+1)!}\cdot \frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+1)!} \cdot \frac{(2n+3)!}{(n+1)!(n+2)!} \cdot \frac{(2n+4)!}{(n+2)!(n+2)!} = \frac 14 \binom{2n+1}{n} \binom{2n+2}{n+1} \binom{2n+3}{n+1} \binom{2n+4}{n+2}.
$$

Notice that $\binom{2s}{s} = 2\binom{2s-1}{s-1}$ ([proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/114345/157345)), which allows us to further simplify the expression:

$$
\sqrt\frac{\det M(k)}{\det M(k+1)} = \binom{2n+1}{n} \binom{2n+3}{n+1},
$$

which is an integer.

Comment: Thanks!. For completeness, let me add that the first equality in the first line of your proof uses a result proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1751118/a-is-an-antisymmetric-matrix-of-even-size-b-is-another-matrix-such-that-b-i).

Comment: Oops! That's a bit embarassing. I used that equality, because I thought it is "obviously" correct for _general_ matrices, which of course is not true. I did double-check numerically some steps of the proof, so that gave me some confidence that derivations are correct, but turns out that equality was correct because of very different reasons (lucky me). Good find by you!

Comment: @user10001, I've included the link you gave in the answer.